# Is there an English word for being half as old as a parent?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Like when you reach 20, and your mother is 40.

Is there a phrase/word/whatever that describes this phenomenon?

Alternatively, is there a word for this with any two (unrelated) people?

Comment: There's not going to be a word or standard phrase for this situation, it's not that uncommon but it's not so frequent that speakers feel the necessity to say it in one word. 1. *My mum's double my age* 2. *I'm half my mum/mom's (her) age* 3. *Mum/mom is twice the age of me*. You're going to have to make do with these.

Comment: Is there a term used for this in your native language (if that language isn't English)?

Comment: Ashamed to say that I'm a native speaker.

Comment: But I would be curious if **any** language has a word for this ;)

Comment: Hang on, what happens when "Bob" is 25 and his mom (Carol) is 45, the age difference is still 20 years but Bob is not going to be half the age of his mother. Maths.. damnit. And when Bob was 10, his mother wasn't 20 years old (I hope not!) So you're talking about a situation that will happen sooner or later to every child, unless their parent was 60+ when they were born i.e. Bob is 60 and his father/mother is 120 years old.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah, which is why I find it strange there is no term to describe it.

Comment: What's wrong with "half my/your/his etc. age" why doesn't that work? How often have you wanted to say that someone is now half or exactly double somebody's age? Once a year? Once a month?

Comment: It does work, I'm just curious :)

Comment: If you twice the age and related that means that you have reached the age that their parent was when they had them. I am not familiar with a term for this. But it might help lead you to the term you are looking for.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think that's the point, the situation is so transitory that there really isn't any need for a term for the situation. It's more a point that you and your parent have reached, a bit like equinox, solstice, zenith and apogee are points that a planet has reached in its orbit, but in the case of the lifetimes it's a situation that will never arise again. I can believe that there is some culture somewhere that celebrates this event and would, therefore have a name for it but I've never heard of one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any particular single word, but you can use phrase **"twice the age"**. It means, person A's age is double than that of person B.

> Bob is twice the age of Sam.

There is a word **twofold** which means *twice as great* , but it can't be used in this situation.

Comment: or "X is _twice as old as_ Y"

Comment: Or, dare I suggest, 'Y is half X's age'

Answer (score 0):

The other way to say it is: **I am now the same age as my mother was when I was born.**  Same meaning, but different emphasis.